# Shortcuts created by installer produced by Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Setup Project

Tags: setup-project

I have a Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project that creates desktop and startup menu shortcuts during the install. The shortcuts created invoke the application if user clicks on them. However, the shortcuts cannot be used as a drop target. Also, the shortcut also cannot be used via SendTo command from Explorer. If you check properties of the shortcut from Explorer, the Target has just the application name and is grayed out (for example, MyApplication).  In the manually created shortcut, the Target has full path to the application (i.e. C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MyApplication.exe). Other settings are the same. Upon farther investigation of the shortcut created by the installer, it turned out that internally the shortcut has the Target pointing to some executable created by the installer: C:\WINDOWS\Installer{6806F37B-0B4F-4002-AB09-380926EC572E}_F9EFFA12305AA4213985DC.exe. I suppose that this intermediate executable is intended to provide some installation integrity check or something like this.   The Icon location is also re-directed to this executable. While the intend may have been good, as I mentioned above, this seems to prevent the shortcut from being recognized as drop and sendto targets. Is there a way to tell the installer to create shortcuts to the actual target and not the intermediate exe?

The SendTo capability of the setup project seems to have an additional problem as it only installs the SendTo shortcuts for the currently logged on user even though “install for all users” is set. It seems that the developer just did incomplete job because it is a bit tricky to install SendTo for all users because “All Users” profile does not support SendTo. Instead, you must install a shortcut into “Default User” profile which will take care of all forthcoming user profiles, then enumerate all existing user profiles and add SendTo to each existing profile. I guess the coder of the Setup Project Shortcuts took a shortcut here…

I currently just let the installer install whatever it wants and then in the post install action modify the installed shortcuts and manually install the sendto shortcuts for all users (as outlined above). This works but I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution to both of those issues.

Comment: I also don't like the strange non-standard shortcut created by the installer. Thanks for sharing your research on the topic. Can you explain how you modify the installer shortcut in the post install? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script to tell VS to create "regular" shortcuts. Set the PostBuildEvent property of your Setup project to:

```
cscript //nologo "{path}\WiRunSql.vbs" "$(BuiltOuputPath)" "INSERT INTO Property(Property, Value) VALUES ('DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS', '1')"
```

And create a WiRunSql.vbs file at the path used above with the following content:

```
' Windows Installer utility to execute SQL statements against an installer database
' For use with Windows Scripting Host, CScript.exe or WScript.exe
' Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
' Demonstrates the script-driven database queries and updates
'
Option Explicit

Const msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly = 0
Const msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact = 1

Dim argNum, argCount:argCount = Wscript.Arguments.Count
If (argCount < 2) Then
    Wscript.Echo "Windows Installer utility to execute SQL queries against an installer database." &_
        vbLf & " The 1st argument specifies the path to the MSI database, relative or full path" &_
        vbLf & " Subsequent arguments specify SQL queries to execute - must be in double quotes" &_
        vbLf & " SELECT queries will display the rows of the result list specified in the query" &_
        vbLf & " Binary data columns selected by a query will not be displayed" &_
        vblf &_
        vblf & "Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved."
    Wscript.Quit 1
End If

' Scan arguments for valid SQL keyword and to determine if any update operations
Dim openMode : openMode = msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly
For argNum = 1 To argCount - 1
    Dim keyword : keyword = Wscript.Arguments(argNum)
    Dim keywordLen : keywordLen = InStr(1, keyword, " ", vbTextCompare)
    If (keywordLen) Then keyword = UCase(Left(keyword, keywordLen - 1))
    If InStr(1, "UPDATE INSERT DELETE CREATE ALTER DROP", keyword, vbTextCompare) Then
        openMode = msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact
    ElseIf keyword <> "SELECT" Then
        Fail "Invalid SQL statement type: " & keyword
    End If
Next

' Connect to Windows installer object
On Error Resume Next
Dim installer : Set installer = Nothing
Set installer = Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer") : CheckError

' Open database
Dim databasePath:databasePath = Wscript.Arguments(0)
Dim database : Set database = installer.OpenDatabase(databasePath, openMode) : CheckError

' Process SQL statements
Dim query, view, record, message, rowData, columnCount, delim, column
For argNum = 1 To argCount - 1
    query = Wscript.Arguments(argNum)
    Set view = database.OpenView(query) : CheckError
    view.Execute : CheckError
    If Ucase(Left(query, 6)) = "SELECT" Then
        Do
            Set record = view.Fetch
            If record Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            columnCount = record.FieldCount
            rowData = Empty
            delim = "  "
            For column = 1 To columnCount
                If column = columnCount Then delim = vbLf
                rowData = rowData & record.StringData(column) & delim
            Next
            message = message & rowData
        Loop
    End If
Next
If openMode = msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact Then database.Commit
If Not IsEmpty(message) Then Wscript.Echo message
Wscript.Quit 0

Sub CheckError
    Dim message, errRec
    If Err = 0 Then Exit Sub
    message = Err.Source & " " & Hex(Err) & ": " & Err.Description
    If Not installer Is Nothing Then
        Set errRec = installer.LastErrorRecord
        If Not errRec Is Nothing Then message = message & vbLf & errRec.FormatText
    End If
    Fail message
End Sub

Sub Fail(message)
    Wscript.Echo message
    Wscript.Quit 2
End Sub
```